# How to add checkboxes to a listview that uses a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-checkbox

I have a listview which uses a `CursorAdapter` to populate the listview. I want to allow users to choose multiple items and perform actions, such as delete items, on all of the selected items at the same time. I tried adding a `CheckBox` item to the layout xml of the item `item_vocab.xml`. The checkbox showed up beside each item, but **I wasn't able to figure out how to keep track of the status of the checked items.** I also tried adding `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)` instead but the checkbox didn't show up.

Here are some of my code:

**item_vocab.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:longClickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36sp"
            android:layout_height="36sp"
            android:id="@+id/vocabLevel"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/level_bars"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:contentDescription="@string/vocab_level"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/vocabName"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/vocabLevel"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/vocabLevel"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/vocabDefinition"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/vocabLevel"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/vocabLevel"
            android:layout_below="@id/vocabName"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_my_vocab.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context="charlesli.com.personalvocabbuilder.io.MyVocabActivity">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mVocabList"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/empty_text_view"
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MyVocabActivity.java**

```
    public class MyVocabActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private VocabCursorAdapter mVocabAdapter;
        private ListView mVocabListView;
        private TextView mEmptyTextView;
        private Cursor mCursor;
        private String mSelectedVocab;
        private CheckBox mCheckBox;

        private VocabDbHelper mDbHelper = new VocabDbHelper(this);

        private ArrayList<String> mCheckedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_vocab);

            mVocabListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mVocabList);
            mEmptyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
            mVocabListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyTextView);
            mCursor = mDbHelper.getCursorMyVocab(mDbHelper);
            mVocabAdapter = new VocabCursorAdapter(this, mCursor, 0);
            mVocabListView.setAdapter(mVocabAdapter);
            mVocabListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            mVocabListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    mSelectedVocab = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vocabName)).getText();
                    editVocabAlertDialog(mSelectedVocab, view, position, id);
                    return true;
                }
            });


        }
```

VocabCursorAdapter.java

```
public class VocabCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private static final int DIFFICULT = 0;
    private static final int FAMILIAR = 1;
    private static final int EASY = 2;
    private static final int PERFECT = 3;


    public VocabCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_vocab, parent, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView tvVocabName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vocabName);
        TextView tvVocabDefinition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vocabDefinition);
        ImageView tvVocabLevel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.vocabLevel);

        String vocab = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(VocabDbContract.DatabaseInfo.COLUMN_NAME_VOCAB));
        String definition = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(VocabDbContract.DatabaseInfo.COLUMN_NAME_DEFINITION));
        int level = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(VocabDbContract.DatabaseInfo.COLUMN_NAME_LEVEL));
        tvVocabName.setText(vocab);
        tvVocabDefinition.setText(definition);
        if (level == DIFFICULT) {
            tvVocabLevel.setImageResource(R.drawable.level_bars_difficult);
        }
        else if (level == FAMILIAR) {
            tvVocabLevel.setImageResource(R.drawable.level_bars_familiar);
        }
        else if (level == EASY) {
            tvVocabLevel.setImageResource(R.drawable.level_bars_easy);
        }
        else if (level == PERFECT) {
            tvVocabLevel.setImageResource(R.drawable.level_bars_perfect);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide further information.

Comment: post your adapter class

Comment: @JaiSoni Thanks, I just posted my CursorAdapter class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomListview for this, make another xml that have textview and checkbox and use that layout in your custom adapter class for populating list then it will work like you want. For example look this tutorial:

```
http://techlovejump.com/android-listview-with-checkbox/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's very detailed and informative. I will try this out as soon as possible. However, I saw that they used (extended) an ArrayAdapter instead of a CursorAdapter (which I used). Does that affect anything? I'll let you know the results once I tried it out.